# Need a bat file to delete a folder with a unique name

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, I'm working on a bat file to delete a file, then find and delete a folder.

It deletes the file just fine, but I'm running into issues with the rest. The folder I'm trying to delete has a different name every time, but contains the same keyword at the start of the folder name every time.

The following line is working to find the folders in question, but I don't know how to actually delete the folder once found.

```
dir C:\location\*keyword*.* /S
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm fine with a code that isn't made for .bat, but it will need to be set to run on startup if it isn't.

I've used both of the following (not at the same time)
to delete the file(s) if found

```
del C:\location\*keyword*.* /S 
rd  C:\location\*keyword*.* /S
```

Comment: I've used both of the following (not at the same time)

   del C:\location\*keyword*.* /S
   rd C:\location\*keyword*.* /S

Comment: You can probably try a for loop - check out the syntax and examples at http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html - try something by modifying their examples and let us know what you did and how it worked out

Comment: Thanks a ton. It *worked* in the sense that it deleted the 2 folders I wanted, but it also deleted about 20 seemingly random (and completely unrelated to the keyword) folders in addition to those 2. lol. Given that my keyword is pretty specific, I know the folders shouldn't have been deleted-- so I'm wondering if you'd know why it happened. If not, it's not a huge issue, it's essentially just deleting other temp files than the 2 folders I'm trying to auto delete.

Thanks again.

Comment: I wasn't too sure whether accepting it now would lock it or not, but I just accepted the answer. The keyword I was using was gw2cache. Thanks again, dude.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out why it did that so I figured it wasn't really an issue with the code-- but it was worth confirming that with you. Either way, all the folders were temp folders so it wasn't a huge issue.

Thanks again for the awesome work

Comment: I'll let you know what it shows once the folder gets repopulated again. Right now the only folders left are the ones it didn't delete originally, so logic would dictate it wouldn't show any results currently.

Thanks again for all the hard work, the next update to this will likely be in around a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the **`DIR`** command with the **`/B`** switch too in a **`FOR /F`** loop and then using **Batch Substitutions** to show only the **Drive Letter** and **Path** of the found folder of the file found in the recursive **`DIR`** command with the string to search for with the "**`keyword`**" and the wildcards as in your example, and then pass that to the **`RD`** command with the **`/Q`** and **`/S`** switches.

---

**Batch Script**

```
 @ECHO ON

 SET keyword=<My Keyword>
 SET searchfolder=C:\Folder\<StartHere>

 CD /D "%searchfolder%"
 FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "*%keyword%*.*"') DO RD /S /Q "%%~DPF"

 GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- **Batch Substitutions (FOR /?)**

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
  > %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
  > %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
  > %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
  > %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
  > %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
  >                environment variable and expands %I to the
  >                fully qualified name of the first one found.
  >                If the environment variable name is not
  >                defined or the file is not found by the
  >                search, then this modifier expands to the
  >                empty string
  > ```

---

### **Testing Script**

*You will need to press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> to move onto each command but **before you press** <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>, be sure to read the entire screen to see what all is found to confirm this is what you are expecting for what will be removed, etc.*

```
 @ECHO ON

 SET keyword=<My Keyword>
 SET searchfolder=C:\Folder\<StartHere>

 CD /D "%searchfolder%"

 ECHO *** Below are the folder path and file names of the files matching "*%keyword%*.*" 

 DIR /S /B "*%keyword%*.*"

 PAUSE
 CLS

 ECHO *** Below are the folder paths that will be deleted  where files were found to reside matching the pattern "*%keyword%*.*"

 FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "*%keyword%*.*"') DO ECHO RD /S /Q "%%~DPF"

 PAUSE

 GOTO EOF
```